# HTACCESS redirect if URL does not contain specific string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have looked through various other posts on here but I can't seem to find any that show how to do a redirect in HTACCESS if the url does NOT contain a specific string.  What I need to do is force HTTPS/WWW to all requests unless the request is for appfeed.domain.com.  In that case, I don't want to redirect at all but just let the request go through.

Here is what I have now.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This works, but it also redirects my appfeed.domain.com requests to [www.appfeed.domain.com](http://www.appfeed.domain.com), which obviously breaks the request.  can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples. This will process requests only for for domain which is not `appfeed.domain.com`. Adding 1st condition as per of that and rest of the conditions from OP's htaccess itself.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !appfeed\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```