# Redirect loop while looking for uri that does NOT contain specific string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an site lets say https://example.com/ and I would like to redirect every url that doesn't begins with `/something` to https://example.com/something/

I'm using Apache 2.4.29 (hosting) and my .htaccess looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/something(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /something/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

My problem is that when I'm on homepage (`/`) or any other page I'm redirected to `/something/` which is correct but when I'm on `/something/` I'm still beeing redirected to `/something/` and it loops until ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error shows up.

[Here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=07760c67-be71-47a5-9480-8d8a805710d4) is a link to htaccess tester which shows that this should work and should not redirect me to `/something/` when I'm already here but it is not the case on my hosting.

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844155/301-redirect-only-if-uri-doesnt-contain-specific-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038778/htaccess-redirect-if-url-does-not-contain-specific-string) question but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following set of rules. Please place them on top of htaccess rules file in case you already have existing rules.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !something [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /something? [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: Checked but without success. When i remove `!` from first `RewriteCond` I'm beeing redirected to `/something/` and too many redirect doesn't show (which is great) but when i type `https://example.com/asd/asdasdasd/asd` I'm not beeing redirected to `/something/`

Comment: @ciekals11, please do let me know if you are testing this on apache not on websites, because online websites are NOT good they will give wrong results and false positive results. Kindly do let me know.

Comment: I have a website that is located on hosting which uses apache web server. I don't know if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: @ciekals11, yes I was asking same where did you tested the rules, since you have tested them on apache  lets move on to next question. Please confirm if you want URL `https://example.com/asd/asdasdasd/asd` to be redirected to `https://example.com/somethingasd/asdasdasd/asd`? If yes then I have updated my rules kindly take a look to those once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: No. I want `https://example.com/asd/asdasdasd/asd` to be redirected to `https://example.com/something/`

Comment: @ciekals11, so it means any url which is NOT something should become something? Please confirm once.

Comment: @ciekals11, sorry I can't chat room, please comment here.

Comment: Yes.  Any url which is NOT something should be redirected to `/something/`

Comment: @ciekals11, sure, then please place my edited Rules at top of your htaccess Rules file and test once.

Comment: Now every uri redirect to `/something/` (great) but unfortunately still getting TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error on `/something/`

Comment: @ciekals11, ok sure, I have edited my Rules now, could you please do check once and let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule with `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/something [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /something/ [R=302,L]
```

Make sure to test it after completely clearing browser cache.

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`